# regex capture middle of url

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to figure out the base regex to capture the middle of a google url out of a sql database.

For example, a few links:

https://www.google.com/cars/?year=2016&model=**dodge**+**durango**&id=1234
https://www.google.com/cars/?year=2014&model=**jeep**+**cherokee**+**crossover**&id=6789

What would be the regex to capture the text to get **dodge+durango** , or **jeep+cherokee+crossover** ? (It's alright that the + still be in there.)

My Attempts:

1) 
    `\b[=.]\W\b\w{5}\b[+.]?\w{7}`
, but this clearly does not work as this is a hard coded scenario that would only work like something for the dodge durango example. (would extract "dodge+durango)

2) Using positive lookback ,

```
[^+]( ?=&id )
```

but I am not fully sure how to use this, as this only grabs one character behind the & symbol.

How can I extract a string of (potentially) any length with any amount of + delimeters between the "model=" and "&id" boundaries?

Comment: please tag the dbms you are using.

Comment: added as redshift. thanks

Answer (score 0):

seems like you could use `regexp_replace` and access match groups:

```
regexp_replace(input, 'model=(.*?)([&\\s]|$)', E'\\1')
```

from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html):

> The regexp_replace function provides substitution of new text for
>   substrings that match POSIX regular expression patterns. It has the
>   syntax regexp_replace(source, pattern, replacement [, flags ]). The
>   source string is returned unchanged if there is no match to the
>   pattern. If there is a match, the source string is returned with the
>   replacement string substituted for the matching substring. The
>   replacement string can contain \n, where n is 1 through 9, to indicate
>   that the source substring matching the n'th parenthesized
>   subexpression of the pattern should be inserted, and it can contain \&
>   to indicate that the substring matching the entire pattern should be
>   inserted. Write \ if you need to put a literal backslash in the
>   replacement text. The flags parameter is an optional text string
>   containing zero or more single-letter flags that change the function's
>   behavior. Flag i specifies case-insensitive matching, while flag g
>   specifies replacement of each matching substring rather than only the
>   first one

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding, but if you want to get the model, just select everything between `model=` and the ampersand (`&`).

```
regexp_matches(input, 'model=([^&]*)')
```

- `model=`: Match literally
- `([^&]*)`: Capture

  - `[^&]*`: Anything that isn't an ampersand

    - `*`: Unlimited times